# Not solutions to a equation

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials

If there are infinitely many points that are not solution to the polynomial equation $F(X_1,X_2,...X_{n-1},1)=0$ then there are infinitely many points that are not solution to the polynomial equation $F(X_1,X_2,...X_{n-1},X_n)$.

Why is that?

Thank you!

P.S. I found the statement [here](https://discretethoughtsblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/fulton_starred_exercise_solutions3.pdf) as a solution to the problem 1.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $F(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is a polynomial, not a polynomial equation. I assume that you mean $F(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$. Then this fact is a trivial observation, since $F(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},1)=0$ is the special case of $F(X_1,\dots, X_n)=0$ with $X_n=1$.

Does this help you? If not, please specify a little more, which part you don't understand and I will try to elaborate on this answer.

Comment: It is not possible that the equation $F(X_1,…,X_{n−1},1)=0$ has infinitely many points that are not solution but the equation $F(X_1,…,X_{n−1},2)=0$ (for example) does have a finite number of points that are not solutions?

Comment: That is possible. But the function in which $X_n$ is not fixed also covers the case $X_n=1$. Just to have a picture in mind, consider the set of solutions to $F(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (or wherever your coefficients live). Then $X_n=1$ is a hyperplane and you are cutting the set of solutions with this hyperplane. You know that in this hyperplane, $F=0$ avoids infinitely many points. So this holds for $F=0$ in particular. On the other hand, when restricting to $X_n=2$, you know nothing about what happens in this hyperplane.